# select distinct table4_id, table3_id, and table2_id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I have 4 tables. I joined them using INNER and RIGHT JOIN. I am trying to select distinct table4_id, table3_id, and table2_id.

**Here's the query to join the 4 tables**

```
      <?php 
             $query = mysqli_query($con, 
                "SELECT 
                      table1.table1_id, 
                      table1.firstname, 
                      table1.middlename, 
                      table1.lastname, 
                      table1.extension_name, 
                      table2.table2_id, 
                      table3.table3_id, 
                      table4.table4_id 
                 FROM table1
                 INNER JOIN table2
                      ON table1.table1_id = table2.table2_id
                 RIGHT JOIN table3
                      ON table2.table2_id = table3.table3_id
                RIGHT JOIN table4
                      ON table3.table3_id = table4.table4_id") or die(mysqli_error($con));

       ?>
```

**Code when I fetch the result**

```
          <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): ?>
               <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['table4_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['table3_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['table2_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['middlename'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['extension_name'];?></td>
                </tr>
           <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Result**

[image]
**Image of what I want to achieve**

[image]

I guess my query is not correct

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` - same result
I tried `GROUP BY` -  it works with table4_id, table3_id, and table2_id column BUT under the "Name" column, it shows only one record. It should show all names  with table2_id

Comment: have you tried using `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Try using `GROUP BY table4_id,tabl3_id,tabl2_id`

Comment: For each group `table4_id,tabl3_id,tabl2_id`, which record do you want to fetch?

Comment: Right joins... Most people find those too confusing. To make code easier to read and easier to maintain, switch to left join! (I.e "main table join optional data", instead of "optional data join main table".)

Answer (score 1):

**You can try using a for loop that loops around the tables content**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query));

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['table4_id'];?></td>

                <td><?php echo $row['table3_id'];?></td>

                <td><?php echo $row['table2_id'];?></td>

                <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " .$row['middlename'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['extension_name'];?></td>
            </tr>
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query is not present aggregation function so the group by is not required

if you want distinct value you must add this clause in you select

```
"SELECT      DISTINCT
                  table1.table1_id, 
                  table1.firstname, 
                  table1.middlename, 
                  table1.lastname, 
                  table1.extension_name, 
                  table2.table2_id, 
                  table3.table3_id, 
                  table4.table4_id 
             FROM table1
             INNER JOIN table2
                  ON table1.table1_id = table2.table2_id
             RIGHT JOIN table3
                  ON table2.table2_id = table3.table3_id
            RIGHT JOIN table4
                  ON table3.table3_id = table4.table4_id"
```